# listing out all the possible combinations of a integer array

Tags: java

Problem: To find all the possible combinations of a given set.

Explanation:

Ex: 1;

Input

3  (no.of elements in the integer array)

0 1 2

Expected output:

(0,1)(0,2)(1,2)

Ex 2

Input

5 (no.of elements)

0 1 2 3 4  (integer array)

Expected output

(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)(0,4)

(1,2) (1,3)(1,4)
(2,3)(2,4)(3,4)

My Implementation:

```
   static void traverse( int[] ar) {
      int n  = ar.length;
      for(int i=0;i<(n-1);i++) {
       for(int j = (i+1);j<n;j++) {
           System.out.printf("%d %d", i,j);
       }
     }
   }
```

Output:
0 10 21 2
Can anyone plz suggest the flaw in the logic  ?

Comment: You never print the elements of the array. You print their index. Other than that, the output is correct: it contains 0 1, then 0 2, then 1 2 as you expect. Of course, it doesn't have parentheses nor commas, since you don't print any.

Comment: It's working, but your formatting is making the output look broken. Change `System.out.printf("%d %d", i,j);` to `System.out.printf("(%d, %d) ", ar[i], ar[j]);`

Comment: Thanks it was a problem with the System.out.printf as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that combination is only limited to two numbers and also I assume that order is not important and rather you are only looking for a combination of numbers instead of permutation.

So here's the modified code for what you've submitted.

```
static void traverse(int[] ar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("(%d,%d) ", ar[i], ar[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This would generate the required answer.